# How to set label text in Windows Forms from a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am currently writing a Level Generator for a game using Windows Forms and C#. I have a `BackgroundWorker` that is doing all of the Generation so that the UI thread is not held up and can update itself as necessary. I currently update a progress bar using the BackgroundWorkers `ReportProgress()` function, but id also like to be able to update a label based on where the generator is at, i.e "Initialising Level 2", "Placing objects in Level 3" etc.

I tried to call the `updateProgress()` function from the backgroundWorker (I pass it and the form into the Generator constructor) to do that but it doesn't work because I get a Cross-Threading error.

```
 public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
        LevelGen Generator;
        List<Level> levelSet;

        public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();;
            Generator = new LevelGen(this, backgroundWorker, timer);
        }



        private void button_GenLevels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
            if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                progressBar.Value = 0;

                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            levelSet = Generator.startGeneration();
        }

        public void updateProgress(int percentage, string currentWork)
        {
            label_processInfo.Text = percentage + " - " + currentWork;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListLevels(levelSet);
        }

    }
```

And it would be getting called like this inside the Generator:

```
public Level generateLevel(int noOfLevels, int noOfBoxes, int roomHeight, int roomWidth, int difficulty, int levelNum, int totalLevels)
        {
            bool generationSuccessful = false;
            Level newLevel = new Level();
            float percentage;
            int indProcesses = 2;
            int totalProcesses = totalLevels * (indProcesses + 1);

            while (!generationSuccessful)
            {
                newLevel = new Level();

                calculateProperties(ref noOfBoxes, ref difficulty, ref roomHeight, ref roomWidth);

                percentage = (((levelNum * indProcesses)) * 100) / totalProcesses;
                form.updateProgress((int)percentage, "Init Level " + levelNum);

                initLevel(ref newLevel, roomHeight, roomWidth);

                percentage = (((levelNum * indProcesses) + 1) * 100) / totalProcesses;
                form.updateProgress((int)percentage, "Placing Patterns in Level " + levelNum);

                placePatterns(ref newLevel, roomHeight, roomWidth);

                generationSuccessful = true;
            }

            percentage = (((levelNum * indProcesses) + 2) * 100) / totalProcesses;
            form.updateProgress((int)percentage, "Level " + levelNum + " Generated");

            return newLevel;
        }
```

How should I tell the Windows Form Label to update from within the Generator?

Comment: You can use the second parameter for of the ReportProgress method, userState, to send data to the backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged method. Then you can get it there from the event argument e.UserState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment i just leaved.

```
 public void updateProgress(int percentage, string currentWork)
    {
        label_processInfo.Text = percentage + " - " + currentWork;
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage,"New Label Value");
    }
 private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        string newLabelValue = (String)e.UserState;
    }
```

Also the user state is an object, so you can send anything you want.

Comment: you need to set the label Text in the ProgressChanged event

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad yes. instead  string newLabelValue = (String)e.UserState; he will need to set the label value. but that is how he gets it from the event argument.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked great! That was a really obvious solution now that I see it.

Comment: @Conor Watson Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a delegate and checking if .InvokeRequired to update UI elements in a thread-safe manner:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
private void SetDebugText(string RxString)
    {
        if (this.btnDebug.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetDebugText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { RxString });

        }
        else
        {
            this.btnDebug.Text = RxString;
        }
    }
```